# Store Large Dataset in Spark and use it across jobs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, factory-pattern, bigdata

I'm generating a large RDD in Spark (~7M Rows; 20 Columns). Source Data is coming from Cassandra
I have 3 Jobs that use this RDD for generating specfic datasets.
Eg : J1(Col1..Col3); J2(Col3..Col20); J3(Col10..Col20);

Requirement : 
I need to generate this RDD just once and use it across J1, J2, J3.

Question :
What would be the best approach to do this ?

What I have Tried Till now :
1. Store the RDD as File on Spark Driver --> let each Job read data out of the file in form of RDD  (got very poor performance)
2. Use Factory Pattern by calling the required Job.. My skeleton in Scala looks like :

```
   agrs(0).split("\\,").foreach{ X =>
     override def execute( jobName : String ) = X match {
              case "J1" =>  new J1()
              case "J2" =>  new J2()
              case "J3" =>  new J3()
              case "J4" =>  new J4DoesNotUseRDD()
      }     
   }
```

Problem here is I dont know how and where to generate my RDD for each job. Also I might have to run J1 and J2 together or just J3.. In the case where I;m running J1 and J2 together I do not want to re-create the RDD.

I'm brainstorming with myself for a better ideas.
Please do let me know if anybody out there has a better ideas for this.

Comment: It sounds kind of what you are looking for is the Spark Job Server, and NamedRDDs 

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#persistent-context-mode---faster--required-for-related-jobs

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#named-objects


Unless you are using a single JVM then you just need to cache your initial RDD

Comment: @RussS : I'm using single JVM.. So cache() or persist() will suffice my requirement ! Thank you for the link.. I will explore NamedRDD in my future projects